# SQL Sub-Query Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, database

I have a dataset containing a list of recorded coronavirus cases in countries across the world through a time period of December 2019 to April 2020. I am trying to write an SQL query to give a  a cumulative total for the top ten countries through this time period (i.e. the countries with the highest total at the end).

I have started this by writing a query to give a cumulative total for all countries, and then have tried to write a sub-query to limit this list to only include the data for the top ten countries.

```
SELECT 
    Virus.dateRep,
    Country.countriesAndTerritories,
    SUM(Virus.cases) OVER (PARTITION BY Country.geoId ORDER BY Dates.year, Dates.month, Dates.day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'cume_cases',
    SUM(Virus.deaths) OVER (PARTITION BY Country.geoId ORDER BY Dates.year, Dates.month, Dates.day ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 'cume_deaths'
FROM    
    Virus
    INNER JOIN 
        Dates ON (Virus.dateRep =  Dates.dateRep)
    INNER JOIN
        Country ON (Virus.geoId = Country.geoId)
WHERE Virus.geoId IN (SELECT 
                        Virus.geoId, sum(Virus.cases) as 'total'
                    FROM    
                        Virus
                    GROUP BY    
                        Virus.geoId
                    ORDER BY
                        total
                        DESC
                    LIMIT 10)
GROUP BY    
    Country.geoId,
    Virus.dateRep
ORDER BY
    Dates.year,
    Dates.month,
    Dates.day,
    Country.countriesAndTerritories
    ASC;
```

However, the sub-query only allows for one column to be queried, and so is not working. Any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Remove the sum from the Select and add it to order by: `order by sum(Virus.cases) desc`

Comment: @cekpowell . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  But now that your code does not work in SQL Server (because of the limit) nor in MySQL (because of the limit in a subquery with `in`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with only one column:

```
WHERE Virus.geoId IN (SELECT v.geoId
                      FROM  Virus v
                      GROUP BY v.geoId
                      ORDER BY sum(Virus.cases) DESC
                      LIMIT 10
                     )
```

Comment: Wow - thank you! Thats worked. Im quite new to SQL so was finding this quite difficult.